# Edge Animate - How can i access and change a text from a button in different symbols?

Tags: adobe-edge

I have this:
ELEMENTS:
Stage  - symbol_1

```
   - symbol_2
```

So,... i would like to change a text inside symbol_2 from a button on symbol_1, using sym.$("Text").html("NewText");  What's the correct path!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click event of symbol_1 -> button write this:

```
var stage = sym.getParentSymbol();
var sym2 = stage.getSymbol("symbol_2");
sym2.$("Text").html("NewText");
```

This code works if both symbol_1 and symbol_2 are children of Stage.
Please note that symbol_1 and symbol_2 are the instances names of the symbols, as they appear in the "Elements" panel (not in the symbol library)

Comment: i can do this as well: sym.getComposition().getStage().getSymbol('symbol_1').$("Text").html("NewText");

Comment: Sure. Your solution is better since you don't have to know that stage is the parent of your symbol. If you change the symbol's hierarchy in the future your code will still work.